# Can't call external rest api within my Lambda function

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have My lambda function configured to a API gateway within a public VPC , but  I am not able to call external web-service (REST api) within my function.
It gives a gateway timeout error.

NOTE : I am trying to call REST API outside My VPC

Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to deploy the lambda function in private subnet and configure a nat gateway to talk to the IG which was configured in a public subnet